# AJAX request returning Javascript won't return a particular function but will return others

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I am new to Javascript, so this might be a easy fix...  What I am trying to do is return some PHP generated Javascript like this:

```
$.ajax({

   type: 'GET',
   dataType: 'script',
   url: "process.php?q=" + nextOne,
   cache: false,
   success: function(result) { 
   var points = poly();
   var view = view();
   console.log(poly());                                   
       }
   });
```

The PHP code which executes on the GET function echo's the following code successfully each time:

```
 function poly() { var polygon = [ [44.0979657883536, -77.59741353683408], [44.09800110003289, -77.59742583167298], [44.0980628953913, -77.59745042091538], [44.09809820673028, -77.59747500869589], [44.09815117444222, -77.59748730467579], [44.09818648579019, -77.59751189254636], [44.09824828154319, -77.59752418914519], [44.09830124890875, -77.59754877818678], [44.09836304401723, -77.59758566057246], [44.09844249510888, -77.59762254440908], [44.09855725698249, -77.5977086026865], [44.09863670785234, -77.59775778001215], [44.0988132654151, -77.5978684291988], [44.09899865055464, -77.59800366685273], [44.099157552135, -77.59812661066638], [44.09925465878388, -77.59820037721019], [44.09930762506249, -77.59827414098369], [44.09936059135786, -77.59834790500194], [44.09938707375796, -77.59840937369948], [44.09942238393646, -77.59848313660127], [44.09944886554787, -77.59856919181473], [44.09946651905435, -77.59865524685266], [44.09946651545066, -77.59876588717155], [44.09946651258768, -77.59885194044027], [44.09946651051048, -77.59891340743259], [44.09946650840645, -77.59897487447928], [44.09944884869306, -77.59907322011854], [44.09942235991026, -77.59919615139923], [44.09936938613104, -77.59933137393786], [44.09929875346595, -77.59952806157649], [44.09922812091607, -77.59971245627803], [44.0991398332644, -77.59985996814586], [44.09907803141549, -77.59997060283777], [44.09901623062632, -77.60005665047542], [44.09893677444724, -77.60011810902354], [44.09889263256964, -77.60014269102098], [44.0988396637248, -77.60014268500156], [44.09879552299976, -77.60014268001041], [44.09875138228544, -77.60014267504206], [44.0986984140636, -77.6001303756445], [44.09864544644561, -77.60010578285841], [44.09859247938493, -77.60006889673586], [44.09850420107129, -77.60000742014995], [44.09846006278729, -77.5999582419273], [44.09834530251719, -77.59984758986654], [44.09823054177884, -77.59974923232423], [44.0980892979686, -77.59962628606064], [44.09794805423672, -77.59950334086375], [44.09781563809948, -77.59939269104248], [44.09773618821324, -77.59933121854448], [44.09762142489915, -77.5992943294499], [44.09755080027261, -77.59929432346378], [44.09746251947693, -77.5992943160516], [44.09738306614857, -77.59930660246103], [44.09725064310649, -77.59934347054637], [44.09714470420811, -77.59938034083626], [44.09691516732349, -77.59950325144526], [44.09665031521845, -77.59966303842049], [44.09636780340659, -77.59985970230275], [44.09595286215229, -77.60013011364448], [44.09589106224593, -77.60016698752585], [44.0958734066763, -77.60015469320798], [44.09582926644982, -77.60014239682909], [44.09579395667541, -77.60009322247899], [44.09576747595455, -77.60003175602542], [44.09574099598146, -77.59995799683112], [44.0957056861353, -77.59990882281723], [44.09567037856668, -77.5998227708729], [44.09562624284954, -77.59973671809175], [44.09553796880017, -77.59960149149188], [44.09547617706166, -77.59950314546113], [44.0953349446695, -77.59917123462215], [44.09529964265098, -77.59897455110928], [44.09525551601103, -77.59870411256358], [44.09524670194121, -77.59842138462815], [44.09524671692267, -77.59810178086126], [44.09524673176193, -77.59775759351884], [44.09524674479974, -77.59742569960808], [44.09525558357575, -77.59713068427324], [44.09529090391865, -77.59689713179387], [44.09530856957198, -77.59657753331807], [44.09530857256068, -77.59646690312057], [44.09530857478986, -77.59638085751901], [44.09530857602622, -77.59633168850351] ]; return polygon; } function view() { var view = [-44.097102112991, 77.59840744055]; return view; }
```

Sorry about how messy that is, but that is the generated code.  So when this executes, the `view();` function will work fine. The poly function, however, does not work.  Safari keeps giving me this error:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: poly

I've tried pasting all the result code into my webpage and it works, but its only when using AJAX that I run into this issue.  If this isn't enough info let me know, this is my first post here.

Thanks in advance,

Will

Comment: Your PHP server should produce JSON, not Javascript.  Then you can use `JSON.parse()` on the receiving end to convert the JSON into Javascript data (or jQuery will do that for you automatically if your PHP tags the data type appropriately).  This is both the safe way to do things and a common way.

Comment: Because poly and view functions are not defined in javascript. Instead of return the entire javascript function. Return jason data from PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the poly() function is in the .php file, then it won't be referenced from the calling .js file. What you can do is look into sending [JSON](http://www.json.org) data across the net. So the PHP file would render out JSON & then you'd use JSON.parse() to turn that back into a JS object.

The PHP would output something like this:

```
{[44.0979657883536, -77.59741353683408], [44.09800110003289, -77.59742583167298], ...}
```

JavaScript file reads that into a data variable & converts it with:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
```

Then your code could look something like this:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   dataType: 'json',
   url: "process.php?q=" + nextOne,
   cache: false,
   success: function(result) {
       var points = JSON.parse(result);
       console.log(points);                                   
   }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! That fixed it, I don't know why I didn't do that in the first place!

Answer (score -1):

it looks like you are making some confusion here. When you request something on server using ajax the browser get the code returned by the server as a string (your response variable). If your PHP emit a valid Javascript function it doesn't mean that it's ready to be executed.

First thing try to console.log() response and see if the reply from the server is what you expect.

Than if your want to execute the code use eval() eval(response) should do the work. eval() take a string with javascript code and execute it.

Keep in mind that eval is evil and it's a poor design choice usually to return javascript code from PHP especially if you want to eval() it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!